# get string matching then store second string and store it

Tags: javascript

have to search  for classname with string matching "Routed:" then get the string of the following classname in this case "W000000" in the image below. there are over 65 of these on the page at any given time i just need to get the first one and store that value.[image]

Comment: Tried `document.getElementsByClassName` ?

Comment: Can you also include your attempt at solving the problem

Comment: var tds = document.getElementsByClassName('ms-cellstyle ms-vb2'); but i cannot figure out how to sort it to obtain the sibling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a for loop for the elements and get the next one.

```
var tds = document.getElementsByClassName('ms-cellstyle ms-vb2');
var found = false;
var firstValue = '';
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length && !found; i++) {
    if (tds[i].innerHTML.indexOf('Routed') >= 0 && i < tds.length - 1) {
        firstValue = tds[i + 1].innerHTML;
        found = true;
    }
}
console.log(firstValue);
```

Comment: this was absolutely simple and perfect, thank you. how would i store the first value as its pulling all of them

Comment: how would i store the first value as its pulling all of them?

Comment: I don't know if I understand correctly what you mean, but you can declare a variable before the loop as `var firstValue;` and inside the `if` in the loop you can assign it using `firstValue = tds[i].innerHTML; ` and the next value as `secondValue = tds[i + 1].innerHTML;` alternately you could use another array and store them as `values.push({firstValue: tds[i].innerHTML, secondValue: tds[i + 1].innerHTML});` Then you could call them as `values[0].firstValue` and `values[0].secondValue`

Comment: this returns the entire list that is Routed: W2342323, W6353732, W27827263. I need to store that first occurence in shit example: "W2342323" as a var. could you add example in your code

Comment: sorry new to this and learning as i go could you pleas update code

Comment: You are welcome, I would be grateful if you could mark the answer as correct.